# Image Background Usage

Tags: react-native, avatar, imagebackground

I am working on a mobile app project with react-native. I got stuck when I was doing the profile screen styling. I want it to look like this image but I can not figure out how to layout the image background and avatar placement like this. If I go for image height and width, image gets half of its height and if a go for flex I couldn't place avatar inside of the image background.

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `resizeMode="cover"` in your `ImageBackground` this will scall image from center read docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode)

and put profile `image` inside `ImageBackground` with `position : 'absolute'`

set [status bar props](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar) to hide status bar background color

this is the code

first `import { View, ImageBackground, Image, StatusBar } from "react-native";`

```js
<View style={{flex : 1}}>

        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="transparent" translucent/>

        <ImageBackground
            style={{width : '100%', aspectRatio : 1.6}}
            resizeMode="cover"
            source={{uri : /*your cover image url here*/}}>

            <View style={{
                position : 'absolute',
                bottom : -50,
                height : 100,
                width : 100,
                borderRadius : 50,
                overflow : 'hidden',
                alignSelf : "center",
                borderWidth : 1,
                borderColor : "#aaa"}}>

                <Image
                    source={{uri : /*your profile image url here*/}}
                    style={{height : 100, width : 100}}/>

            </View>

        </ImageBackground>
    </View>
```

and this my results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `height: '100%'` and `width: '100%'` in your `ImageBackground` style?